# Populate a java collection from GUI

Tags: java, arrays, forms

I want to create a collection with Objects (Persons) received through a GUI form.

Form has name, surname and phone number as text field and an Add button.
on-click to the "Add" button a new Person is created using the data entered in text fields.

I am stuck with how to store all these Persons in a collection in another class.
I tried the below codes:

```
 List collection = new ArrayList();
 collection.add(p);
```

where `p` is the `person`.
This doesn't works.What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Best practice for GUI programming is some sort of MVC pattern: 
http://www.austintek.com/mvc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Class `Person` with all the required fields - name, surename, phonenumber as `members` of this class. Create a new instance of Person and set these fields appropriately and add it to the `ArrayList` instance

```
 //instantiate a new list to store Person objects
 static List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
 //Create a new Person instance
 Person personObject = new Person();
 //set the fields in the person instance
 personObject.setName(name);
 personList.add(personObject);
```

The code for adding the Person into the personList must be added into the `actionListener#actionPerfomed(ActionEvent event)` method for **Add** button.
You should make the members of the Person class as **private** and have the setters and getters as **public**. You can mark the List instance as `static`. so, that the collection will be shared across instances.All Person instances added to the list will be preserved.Hope this helps!

Comment: I created the Person class with all the fields. Also I created another class with an addPerson method in which i entered all the code you gave me. I receive an illegal start of expression for instanciation the new list and 2 other errors: package personObject and personList does not exist.

Comment: I got rid of all of those errors but my personList still doesn't record the Persons. What code should I write for adding the Person into the personList, as you stated above. Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code? it will help me to help you.

Comment: It worked. I managed to save the Persons in the personList collection. Thanks a lot Keerthi !

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is to have a reference **mlc** on the container class object in the GUI:

```
class myGUI   ...    {

    MyListContainer mlc = new MyListContainer();

    public void actionPerformed(...) {
        ... // here you create the Person object
        mlc.pl.add( aPerson);
    }
```

The container class itself could has this code:

```
public class MyListContainer {
    public List<Person> pl = new ArrayList<Person>();
    ...    
}
```